# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hive.service.cli.TableSchema

Tags: java, hive

I am trying to connect to hive using Java. This is my code. I am running it in Eclipse Oxygen. My Java version is 8.

```
private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException 
{
    try 
    {
        Class.forName(driverName);
    } 
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    } 

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://<ip>:<port>/database", "username", "password");      
    String sql = "select * from tablename";
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();             
    stmt.executeQuery(sql);     
}
```

I am able to create table and insert data into table using the above method. But whenever I try to retrieve data from table it throws the following error.

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hive.service.cli.TableSchema.<init>(Lorg/apache/hive/service/cli/thrift/TTableSchema;)
```

Given below are the jars I am using. They have the classes given in the error.

```
commons-logging-1.2
curator-client-2.0.0-incubating
hadoop-common-2.7.3
hadoop-common-3.1.0
hive-exec-3.0.0
hive-jdbc-1.1.0
hive-metastore-3.0.0
hive-service-1.1.0
hive-service-3.0.0
hive-service-rpc-2.1.0
httpclient-4.5.6
httpcore-4.4.10
libfb303-0.9.3
libthrift-0.9.3
log4j-1.2.17
slf4j-api-1.8.0-beta2
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error might be caused by incompatible library versions. You have multiple jar versions of the same libs in your project. Therefore at runtime it will not be clear switch one is used.
get rid of the duplicates and use only the newer versions of `hadoop-common`, `hive-service`.

Comment: I tried doing that. But when I remove the duplicate jars I get the error "NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hive/service/cli/thrift/TCLIService$Iface".

Comment: Hey, i fixed it. You were right about duplicate jars. But instead of older versions I removed newer versions and it worked. Thanks.